# How to fetch fetching data from an ini file using selenium webdriver and testNG

Tags: testng, ini

@DataProvider(name="creds")

```
protected Object[][] returnCreds() {
    Properties cred = new Properties();
    try {
 FileInputStream input = new 
        FileInputStream(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "cred.properties");
        cred.load(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        ApiHelper.doLog(e.getMessage(),false,ApiHelper.logVerbosity.ERROR);
    }
    Object[][] creds = new Object[1][2];
    creds[0][0] = cred.getProperty("user");
    creds[0][1] = cred.getProperty("pass");
    return creds;
}

@Test(dataProvider="creds")
protected void testCreds(String username, String password) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(username + password);
}
```

This is the piece of code i found in internet.I need to use a .ini file to input data.I want to convert this as the code to read data from ini file.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same code to read from .ini file. 
Did you try reading an INI file using the above code ?

```
    public static void readIniFile(){

    Properties cred = new Properties();
    try {
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("legacy.ini");
        cred.load(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //ApiHelper.doLog(e.getMessage(),false,ApiHelper.logVerbosity.ERROR);
    }

    Object[][] creds = new Object[1][2];
    creds[0][0] = cred.getProperty("user");
    creds[0][1] = cred.getProperty("pass");

    System.out.println(creds[0][0]);
    System.out.println(creds[0][1]);
}
```